# Why do my UIBarButtonItem's do an animated slide-in when presenting a view controller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation, swift, uitoolbar

In my iOS app, I present a view controller whose `modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`. When the controller appears, the text UIBarButtonItem's in its toolbar perform a weird slide animation as the controller is flipped into place.

I don't want this animation to happen. How can I prevent it?

**Edit**: Thanks to the brevity of Swift, here's a complete example that reproduces the problem:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        let vc = TestVC()

        self.window!.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

        return true
    }
}

class PresentedVC: UIViewController {
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        toolbarItems = [UIBarButtonItem(title: "Foo", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)]
        modalTransitionStyle = .FlipHorizontal
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.navigationController!.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
    }
}

class TestVC: UITableViewController {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "noId")
        cell.textLabel.text = "Foo"
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        let vc = PresentedVC()
        let nvc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

        self.presentViewController(nvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to set the navigationBar.hidden to FALSE? Isn't it false by default?

Comment: No, it's true by default.

Comment: Yup, I was thinking about navigationBar and you are using toolBar. Instead of setting setToolbarHidden to False in viewWillAppear, I tried setting it to false in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in the TestVC. It worked here, the animation is normal. Would this work in your case?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by making the call in `viewDidLoad` so that the toolbar is always visible right when the controller is constructed. Then I used `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:` to, respectively, show and hide the controller so other controllers in the navigation controller don't have a toolbar if they're not supposed to have one.